# How to pull the correct decimal format from the database when the browser is not on an en-US english operating system

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

Default EditorFor() declares the input field as text and loads the value from the database fine, but displays it with a coma as a separator because the browser is running on non US version of Windows and upon validation of the form it fails on that field if it hasn't been changed and/or someone types in a decimal number with a coma instead of a dot.

If I define the field as number I get a warning in the console:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DecimalNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="number" } })
```

gives

```
jquery-3.4.1.js:4817 The specified value "0,00" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

The number is proper decimal(18, 4) in the database, using entity framework 6 it's also set as such in the model, I haven't set the Web.Config globalization settings, and I don't know what changes the dot into a coma. I can type in decimal numbers with either dots or comas as separators, and jquery validate is happy with either.

How can I get the value loaded in the field when the form loads? I tried adding the @lang="en" attribute in the Editor constructor, but it didn't make any difference either.

Comment: when you debug in the controller, the value of ``DecimalNumber`` is with coma or dot?

Comment: The value has a dot as decimal separator.

Comment: and in the front side, is with coma? or during the form save?

Comment: When the form is displayed the value has a coma instead of a dot.

Comment: try this ``m.DecimalNumber.ToString("f2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`` in your html code

Comment: Can't process the value like that in the view, I get the following Error: `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions`